# Using Query Binding Fuelphp

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fuelphp

i'm have problem problem when i want to [using query fuelphp binding](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/database/usage.html#binding)  on `IN()` mysql function

this is my code

```
$status_array = array(1,2,3);
$query = 'select * from users where status IN(:status_id_as_array)' ;
$user = DB::query($query)->bind('status_id_as_array',$status_array)->execute();
```

from that code the result is zero, when i'm debug with

```
echo DB::last_query();
```

the last query is

```
select * from users where status IN('1,2,3');
```

i think the problem is `IN('1,2,3')` the value of IN is string so it's cannot be execute as array mode.

***Note i can goal with another way***

```
 $query = 'select * from users where status IN('.implode(',', $status_array).')' ;
```

**my question is**

1. it's Query Binding not support IN() function of mysql ? please explain
2. there are another way to Query Binding with IN() function of mysql on fuelphp?

thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

there is another way to go with your query. try:

```php
$user = DB::select()->from('users')
    ->where('status', 'in', $status_array)
    ->execute();
```

it will execute query like: `` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` IN (1, 2, 3) ``

Comment: in other case I do not see any way how to execute it.. except yours 'other way'